# Loop to gather iPhoto MetaData cannot find file

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to loop through all photos in dir created by Mac's `iPhoto` and create list containing each photos meta-data.

`iPhoto` stores all videos and images in the folder named `db` here. I gathered up all of the sub-directories of `db` and stored them in list `folders`

When I loop through the `folders` list and try to collect the meta-data (exif), I am getting an error telling me the file does not exist. I'm not sure how that can be since I did not give the loop any file names. When I count the instances of loops, I get the expected amount of photos. I am just having a hard time looping over the photos to collect meta.

Why am I getting this error? How can I resolve? I'm not sure how a file cannot exist when the loop itself generated that file name to search

```
from PIL import Image
import os

db = "/Users/Scott/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary/Masters/"

folders = []
for i, j, y in os.walk(db):
    folders.append(i)

num = 0
meta_data = []

for folder in folders:
    for photo in os.listdir(folder):
        if photo.endswith(".JPG") or photo.endswith(".PNG") or photo.endswith(".jpg"):
            num = num + 1
            img = Image.open(photo)
            meta = img.getexif()
            meta_data.append(meta)


print(num)
print(len(meta_data))
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Scott/PycharmProjects/EXIF/EXIT.py", line 29, in <module>
    img = Image.open(photo)
  File "/Users/Scott/PycharmProjects/EXIF/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2652, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'IMG_0438.JPG'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

---

*mac os*, *PyCharm*, *Python3*

Comment: Please let me know if I need to clarify anything here. VBA fluent here and I am trying to learn Python as VBA is dying a slow and painful death so i'm just doing this strictly for practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was misunderstanding how the photo loop worked. The actual path I want to open is a combination of both loops

`img = Image.open(folder + "/" + photo)`

Comment: This was the issue but the code still doesn't work. sheesh